# VPC Route list as input to jinja

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jinja2, google-deployment-manager

I am trying to get the list of available default routes and then delete them.

I have the following code

**config.yaml**

```
imports:
- path: action-1.jinja
- path: action-2.jinja

resources:
- name: action-1
  type: action-1.jinja
- name: action-2
  type: action-2.jinja
  properties:
    routes: $(ref.action-1.defaultlist)
```

**action-1.jinja**

```
resources:
- name: default-routes
  action: 'gcp-types/compute-v1:compute.routes.list'
  properties:
    project: 'PROJECT_ID'
    filter: name=default*
outputs:
- name: defaultlist
  value: $(ref.default-routes.items)
```

**action-2.jinja**

```
{% set routes = properties['routes'] %}

resources:
{% for route in routes %}
- name: delete-{{ route.name }}
  action: gcp-types/compute-v1:compute.routes.delete
  properties:
    route: {{ route.name }}
    project: 'PROJECT_ID'
  metadata:
    runtimePolicy:
    - CREATE
{% endfor %}
```

I am getting following error... Not sure why route.name is empty and if routes are empty then why for loop is getting executed.

```
Manifest expansion encountered the following errors: Resource name 'delete-' is not unique in action-2.jinja. Resource: {'name': 'delete-', 'action': 'gcp-types/compute-v1:compute.routes.delete', 'metadata': {'runtimePolicy': ['CREATE']}, 'properties': {'project': 'PROJECT_ID', 'route': None}} Resource: config
```

**Edit#1** I think I know the issue and that is when I pass the list as output o the main YAML it is there as a string so for loop in the 2nd jinja is not working but I am not sure how to convert this string to JSON/List/Dict...